# design of json <-> server for large complex objects

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

I have a HTML/KendoUI/jquery front end that has several places where the user enters in large amounts of form data - think 50+ fields.  I have REST endpoints that are expecting JSON objects that look something like this pseduocode:

```
patient {

firstname:"",
lastname:"",
birthdate:"",
address: {
     street1: ""
     street2: ""
     city:""
     state:""
     zip:""    
}
user: {
   username: "",
   password:"",
   userrole: {
    id:""
    description:""
}
contacts {
   contact {
     id: "",
     type:"",
     number:""
    }
}
}
```

I can take my Java objects and return them this way, but I am struggling on how to convert my form values to such a complex json structure.  KendoUI doesn't appear to support this, and with so many parameters I don't want to manually send them to manually assemble them.

How are large datasets handled in json like this?  Is my expectation to send/receive complex json all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What are the relationships between the Address, user and the main record?  If it's always one to one you should be able to bind the Kendo grid to the your structure.  You'd need to bind the sub object fields with their parent as part of the name (e.g. address.street1).

That said having 50 columns on one grid won't be the most user friendly interface. Have you considered adding buttons on he grid for Address, User, Contacts etc. that will launch a pop up window where the data can be entered?

Comment: For the most part, a patient will have one of each of these nested classes, but there are a few, such as contacts that are OneToMany.  I can get the data displayed on a page, but its the sending from the form to the server that is causing me problems.

Comment: Make sure you're doing JSON.stringify(myObject) on your object before passing it to the server.